# Copy files from old HDD with 14.04 - only shows grub folder

Tags: nautilus, directory

In my laptop I have installed a shiny new SSD drive with a clean install of 16.04.

Then plugged in my old HDD (via a dock and USB) with Ubuntu 14.04 installed, to copy my files across.

But in Nautilus it only shows a 255mb partition with a grub folder.

Is there a way around this to see my old home folder?

Thanks

[image: grub_folder]

Comment: Start the **Disks** utility, there you can select your disk and partition and mount it or maybe see why it fails.

Comment: Try the above and you may find out your drive is encrypted.